# What do I specify for "Rope project root folder: . " with python files and RopeVim plugin?

Tags: python, vim, macvim

I've installed the plugin RopeVim (using Pathogen) and it seems to be working.

Now when I call `:RopeGoToDefinition` with my vim cursor (in command mode) on a function I'd like to see the definition of...I get:

> Rope project root folder: .

displayed in the status line of my vim (fwiw, I'm using MacVim).

What is the proper folder to specify here?

My project folder structure has a root folder, and various subdirs.  I can't even tell if I should be specifying a system filepath or a python-style module.

Comment: I've now learned that a `.ropeproject` folder is created once this question is answered on first call to Rope.  There are more configuration possibilities in there, including the ability to set some python path options.

Comment: As an alternative I suggest `jedi-vim` to you, whose GoToDefinition works amazingly well out of the box. 
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim

Comment: Which version do you use? I had some troubles with latest version on Windows. With version 0.7.8b everything is working fine out the box for me. And +1 regarding `jedi-vim` for completion at least!

Comment: Two comments that don't answer your question but could be useful. I'd really like to recommend `Vundle` over `Pathogen`, it is super easy to keep all of your plugins up-to-date. Also I would like to recommend `jedi-vim` instead of `Rope`, purely because it works so well out of the box for me and I've heard of many people migrating from ropeVim to jedi-vim.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/overview.rst#ropeproject-folder and the Getting Started section of https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/README.rst

You can stick it anywhere, but you probably want to use the root directory of your project.  Note how the prompt defaults to `.`, the current directory.  If your file is in the root directory, you can just hit Enter to accept that default.  Otherwise, try something like `../..` or `/path/to/root`.